# Tengo un error al unir archivos por ID

Tags: c#

Tengo que crear un form que sirve para guardar los datos de una app, usuario y contraseña. Es un código que es para unir tres archivos (nombre de app, usuario y contraseña) y los tengo que unir por un ID, adjunto el código para que vean como lo hice pero me da error el tema del ID y no se como hacerlo.

El error principal es en donde dice `int TotalL(string Patharchivo)`, también sé que no es la manera mas efectiva de hacerlo pero es un ejercicio de practica:

```
     int TotalL(string Patharchivo)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (File.Exists(Patharchivo))
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Patharchivo, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader leerarchivo = new StreamReader(archivo);
                while (leerarchivo.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
                leerarchivo.Close();
                archivo.Close();
                return i;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                lblmensage.text = error.Message;
                grpMensage.show;
                return 0;
            }
           else
            {
                return 0;
            }
    }

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        bool K = false;
        if(textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            label5.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Visible = false;
        }
        if(textBox2.Text == "" && K == false)
        {
            label6.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label6.Visible = false;
        }

        if (textBox3.Text == "" && K == false)
        {
            label7.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label7.Visible = false;
        }
        if (textBox3.Text != textBox4.Text && K == false)
        {
            label8.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label8.Visible = false;
        }
        if(K == false)
        {
            label9.Visible = true;
           
            int secue = 0;
        
            secue = TotaL("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/contraseña.txt");

            secue++;

            FileStream archpass = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/contraseña.txt", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream archuss = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/usuario.txt", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream archapp = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/app.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader abrirpass = new StreamReader(archpass);
            StreamReader abriruss = new StreamReader(archuss);
            StreamReader abrirapp = new StreamReader(archapp);


            string reg;
            string reg1;
            string reg3;

            reg = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox1.Text;
            reg1 = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox2.Text;
            reg3 = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox3.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero que error te dice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu codigo y como no especificas el error entiendo que te falta cerrar con una `}` el metodo `TotalL` en el bloque del `if` y cuando pasas la ruta del archivo te falta `@` o agregar doble `\\` en la ruta, tambien tenes la barra `/` en lugar `\` que es la que se usa para ruta de archivos. Por otro lado la ruta es bastante larga si te da error cambia a una ruta mas corta.

```
private int TotalL(string Patharchivo)
{
        int i = 0;
        if (File.Exists(Patharchivo))
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream archivo = new FileStream(Patharchivo, FileMode.Open);
                StreamReader leerarchivo = new StreamReader(archivo);
                while (leerarchivo.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
                leerarchivo.Close();
                archivo.Close();
                return i;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                lblmensage.text = error.Message;
                grpMensage.show;
                return 0;
            }
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        bool K = false;
        if(textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            label5.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Visible = false;
        }
        if(textBox2.Text == "" && K == false)
        {
            label6.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label6.Visible = false;
        }

        if (textBox3.Text == "" && K == false)
        {
            label7.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label7.Visible = false;
        }
        if (textBox3.Text != textBox4.Text && K == false)
        {
            label8.Visible = true;
            K = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label8.Visible = false;
        }
        if(K == false)
        {
            label9.Visible = true;
           
            int secue = 0;
        //Se agrega @ o \\ para que la cadena tome esos caracteres especiales, y podrias evitar rutas tan largas que tiene cierta capacidad de longitud.

            secue = TotaL(@"C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\facultad\primer año\segundo cuatrimestre\programacion\trabajo integrador\contraseña.txt");

            secue++;

            FileStream archpass = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/contraseña.txt", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream archuss = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/usuario.txt", FileMode.Open);
            FileStream archapp = new FileStream("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop/facultad/primer año/segundo cuatrimestre/programacion/trabajo integrador/app.txt", FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader abrirpass = new StreamReader(archpass);
            StreamReader abriruss = new StreamReader(archuss);
            StreamReader abrirapp = new StreamReader(archapp);


            string reg;
            string reg1;
            string reg3;

            reg = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox1.Text;
            reg1 = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox2.Text;
            reg3 = Convert.ToString(secue) + ";" + textBox3.Text;
        }
    }
```